# Expand the default size of a thumbnail, Wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Here's the site in question:

http://www.xwmarketmakers.com/

Notice how the images on the front page look like they are badly scaled, because they are. The default theme template is this:

http://andersnoren.se/themes/rowling/

The thumbnails load at 400 x 200 and to get the look I want, I've basically just stretched the thumbnails out. Is there a way to get the thumbnail to load the full size images and scale down so the pictures aren't out of focus?

I think the relevant PHP is here:

**`add_image_size( 'post-image-thumb', 400, 200, true);`**

Found in the theme function.php. I've tried editing the values to 1200 x 600 but no cigar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following line in the [content.php](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/rowling/1.04/content.php) file

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image-thumb'); ?>
```

For this one

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
```

The function [the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) loads the image with a certain size, using the `full` argument the function will return the full-size image.

Also, I have to say that you need to use [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to override the parent theme and not lose your changes on new updates

Comment: That worked thanks! I've recently switched to serverpilot, been too laze to install an ftp and create the child theme. :(

Comment: If it works, mark the answer as correct to help others.